# Laravel artisan serve, reload php.ini file

Tags: php, laravel

I use `php artisan serve` to run my Laravel project locally. I got a memory exhausted error so wanted to increase the limit set in `php.ini`.

I used `php -i` to check that the ini file that's loaded is `/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini`

Then through `sudo nano /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini` I've set `memory_limit=1024M`. If I open it there I can see it's saved correctly.

But when I then run `php -i` again I can see the line `memory_limit => 256M => 256M`, so it's not updated.

I've restarted my computer, but I think I need to restart the service in order for these changes to take effect? How do I do this for the service that's behind `artisan serve`?

Comment: "php artisan serve"  is not a good way for long term programming. You should use wamp/lamp/mamp (depends on your OS) or docker containers.

Comment: “long term programming” :-D. Maybe you’re right, depending on what you mean. But serving my app through artisan works really well for me, and for all the projects I’m working on. I actually have MAMP Pro but instantly stopped using it after switching to Laravel. MAMP is a nightmare, every time I upgrade to a new macOS version I have to spend a day figuring out how to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas: 1) Check if there aren't multiple lines in PHP.ini that set this limit. 2) check if there are multiple PHP.ini files loaded.  3) check if your command-line PHP.ini uses a different PHP.ini than your webserver. 4) you can search with grep -r in all your configuration files to look for where that 256 is set.

Comment: If I run `php -i` there's a line `Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini` so that would be the one that's loaded?

Comment: It is the one used by the commandline php binary. I don't know if artisan uses the CLI php.ini or a different one. If you have a page rendered by laravel and you use phpinfo() you can see which php.ini is used

Comment: Have you figured this one out yet?

Comment: Not really. I actually ended up using ini_set(‘memory_limit’, ‘1024M’) in my script.

Comment: That is a horrible solution, but it works. Did you try any other of the 4 ideas I mentioned?